# ReactJS app working in localhost but showing blank screen after publishing in github

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, vite

I used vite to create react app and deploy it. Followed all the instructions correctly but the website is all blank. Can somebody help me with this,

Github respositories link - https://github.com/afratara/travel_journal-reactjs.git

link of the website - https://afratara.github.io/travel_journal-reactjs/

I followed the following youtube tutorial - https://youtu.be/XhoWXhyuW_I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the base configuration option in `vite.config.js` to `'/travel_journal-reactjs/'` as that is where your site is being served from (not `'/travel_journal'`).

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/travel_journal-reactjs/'
})
```